# Differences between Crypt.crypt() and DigestUtils.md5() in apache.commons.Codec

Tags: java, hash, md5, apache-commons, apache-stringutils

I am writing a basic password cracker for the MD5 hashing scheme against a Linux `/etc/shadow file`.  When I use `commons.codec`'s `DigestUtils` or `Crypt` libraries, the hash length for them are different (among other things).

When I use the `Crypt.crypt(passwordToHash, "$1$Jhe937$")` the output is a 22-character string.  When I use the `DigestUtils.md5[Hex](passwordToHash + "Jhe937")`(or the Java `MessageDigest` class) the output is a 32-character string (after converted).  This makes no sense to me.

---

aside: is there no easy way to convert the `DigestUtils.md5(passwordToHash)`'s `byte[]` to a String.  I've tried all* the ways and I get all non-valid output: `Nz_èJÓ_µù[î¬y`

*all being: `new String(byte[], "UTF-8")` and convert to char then to String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The executive summary is that while they'll perform the same hashing, the output format is different between the two so the lengths will be different. Read on for details.

MD5 is a message digesting algorithm that produces a 16 byte hash value, always (assuming valid input, etc.) Those bytes **aren't** all printable characters, they can take any value from 0-255 for any of the bytes, while the printable characters in ASCII are in the range 32-126.

DigestUtils.md5(String) generates the MD5 of the string and returns a 16 element byte array. DigestUtils.md5Hex(String) is a convenience wrapper (I'm assuming, I haven't looked at the source, but that's how I'd write it :-) ) around DigestUtils.md5 that takes the 16 element byte array md5 produces and base16 encodes it (also known as hex encoding). That replaces each byte with the equivalent two hex characters, which is why you get a 32 character String out of it.

Crypt.crypt uses a special format that goes back to the original Unix method of storing passwords. It's been extended over the years to use different hash/encryption algorithms, longer salts, and additional features. It also encodes it's output to be printable text, which is where the length difference is coming from. By using a salt of "$1$...", you're saying to use MD5, so the password plus the salt will be hashed using MD5, resulting in 16 bytes as expected, but because those bytes aren't necessarily printable, the hash is base64 encoded (using a slightly different alphabet than the standard base64 encoding), which replaces 3 bytes with 4 printable characters. So 16 bytes becomes 16 / 3 * 4 = 21-1/3 characters, rounded up to 22.

On your aside, DigestUtils.md5 produces 16 bytes, but those bytes can have any value from 0 to 255 and are (effectively) random. new String(byte[], "UTF-8") says the bytes in the byte array are a UTF-8 encoding, which is a very specific format. new String does it's best to treat the bytes as a UTF-8 encoded string, but because they're really not, you generally get gibberish out. If you want something printable, you'll have to use something that takes random bytes, not bytes in a specific format (like UTF-8). Two popular options are base16/hex encoding, which you can get with DigestUtils.md5Hex, or base64, which you can get with Base64.encodeBase64String(DigestUtils.md5(pwd + salt)).

Comment: Thank you for the thorough response.  This was very helpful in understanding.  It is frustrating that Crypt.crypt is a back ported hack that doesn't seem to conform to the MD5 standard.

Comment: You're welcome. It's not that it doesn't conform to MD5, it's that the output format is different because it conforms to a *different* standard. Can't have enough standards! :-)